# Install php5-dev Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, thread-safety, ubuntu-16.04

I am following this tutorial to enable thread safety in php 5.6.
https://blog.bensoer.com/compile-thread-safe-php-5-6-20-from-source/
But when i am executing `sudo apt-get install -y php5-dev` It gives me the following output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-dev' has no installation candidate
```

How can I resolve this in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install -y php5.6-dev` did the trick

Comment: "Unable to locate package php5.6-dev" as of 2020